# Power BI Calculated Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with two columns, Date & Sales. I'm trying to create a calculated measure. I have a calendar slicer with which I can select between dates. After I select the end date, I want to check if the end date selected is a weekday or a weekend, if it's a weekend I want to take the avg of sales of the dates on the weekday, ie Sum of sales From (Monday to Friday)/5. If I select any weekday, I want it to return The avg sales from the previous week(Monday to Friday).

Comment: Does your Date table have a column for the weekday that corresponds to each row?

Comment: I think, I can create that with Dax and Weekday function.